# Custom color/content of safeareaview bottom padding

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using `react-navigation` in `react-native app`. `react-navigation` does have it prebuilt `SafeAreaView`. However,I have very specific design for the bottom padding of `SafeAreaView` as follow:

1) Customize the color of SafeAreaView, namely, I need to specify a custom single color of the bottom padding in the red box. The specify custom single color may/may not be the same as the top padding color, and it varies from one screen to another. So i need to be able to explicitly state that this screen need this specific color.

eg: `<SafeAreaView bottomPaddingColor={'green'}></SafeAreaView>`

[image]

2) Custom design content (eg: I need 2 color). One of the example is that the footer on the page is button of 2 diff color split into 50% width each. The design specifically needs the bottom padding to follow the button color as shown.

eg: `<SafeAreaView bottomPaddingColor={'green,red'}></SafeAreaView>`
which auto split the color equally width.

or anyway to customize the `bottomPadding` component, where i can include following component as bottom padding.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', height: '100%'}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1, height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'red'}}></View>
    <View style={{flex: 1, height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'green'}}></View>
</View>
```

eg:

[image]

I have read the `SafeAreaView` documentation provided by `react-native` and `react-navigation` but did not find such customization available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you can render multiple `SafeAreaViews`, the following should acheive what you are after:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <Text>Content Goes here</Text>
            </View>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 0 }}>
          <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
          <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green' }} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With React Navigation v6 (Expo v44) on Android, it looks like there's no way to change that area's color other than using the top-level `androidNavigationBar` option in `app.json`:

```
"androidNavigationBar": {
  "backgroundColor": "#000000"
}
```

If you want to change that color dynamically, you can use
[`NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync()`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/navigation-bar/#navigationbarsetbackgroundcolorasynccolor). Install the module using `expo install expo-navigation-bar`, and then in your component:

```
import * as NavigationBar from "expo-navigation-bar";

// ...

NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync("#000000");
```

Sorry for hijacking this thread, but it's the best description of the issue I've found, and I've wasted a good half an hour looking for a solution. Hope it can help the next unlucky dev :)